# Issues when syncing LineageOS repo after adding a local manifest

Tags: android, compilation, lineageos

Recently, when compiling `LineageOS 17.1` for the device `j7y17lte (Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro`), I keep getting the error

```
fatal: duplicate path packages/resources/devicesettings in ~/android/lineage/.repo/manifest.xml
```

This happenes when I add any local manifest to the `.repo/local_manifests` folder (I'm using [this one](https://github.com/mentos1386/lineageos-build/blob/master/local_manifest/j7y17lte.xml)) and run repo sync, and nothing I have read on stackoverflow when people have the same problem has seemed to fix it.
Any help?
Feel free to comment if you need more information.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.